# PHP-FPM output errors to be handled by php application with nginx

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, docker

I'm having difficulty setting up a docker container with phpfpm to defer error handling to my php application.

Any fatal exceptions are being processed by the xdebug stack trace (http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace) as 200 OK, however I want to have the errors handled by the php handler (I want to restructure the error as json, and set response code to 500).

If I set `display_errors = Off` in php.ini I get a code 500 which is good, but no error passed to the application layer (white screen of death).

For both cases above logging is working as intended.

To be clear, everything is functioning as normal (happy path is running fine) but when I intentionally cause a fatal error (It might happen in the future) I have issues.

How should I configure phpfpm/nginx to make sure the fatal errors are handled by the php application?

PHP-FPM config (dockerfile): https://github.com/nglume/docker-phpfpm/blob/master/Dockerfile

nginx config: https://github.com/nglume/docker-nginx/blob/master/config/nginx.conf

vhost: https://github.com/nglume/nglume/blob/master/vhosts/nginx/nglume-api.local.conf

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming these are runtime errors you're talking about, are you using [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set_error_handler)? Also, does your implementation work in any other environments, (e.g. could docker be the problem, what about non php-fpm envs?)

Comment: Why do you have xdebug in this build at all?

Comment: @zamnuts Yep I have confirmed an error handler is being registered (by the lumen framework). I haven't tried outside of a docker environment, I'll look into that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm using xdebug in dev for breakpoints with phpstorm. It will not be used in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a combination of phpfpm pool status `php_flag[display_errors]` was on *and* the lumen application did not have a registered handler for `register_shutdown_function` (it did have a `set_error_handler` set).

See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/lumen-debug-mode-not-showing-stack-trace for more info